# Trouble with @GET service with MongoDB

Tags: java, json, mongodb, rest, get

I need to build a REST Service for MongoDB in Java but I have some trouble to showing the result (a JSON) in the URI web page.
This is the code to communicate, take data from the DB and build the JSON (using Google library Gson):

```
public String getInfo() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("unicorns").find();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(final Document document) {
                sb.append(document);
            }
        });

        String id = gson.toJson(sb);

        return id;
    }
```

This is the @GET function in the RESTful web service:

```
@GET
@Path("/DB")
@Produces("application/json")
public String getJson() {
    ExampleMethods em = new ExampleMethods();
    return em.getInfo();
}
```

And this is what I see in the URI web page:

```
"Document{{_id\u003d554c724b1094a1039086df1c, name\u003dAurora, dob\u003dThu Jan 01 01:00:01 CET 1970, loves\u003d[carrot, grape], weight\u003d450.0, gender\u003df, vampires\u003d43.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df1d, name\u003dHorny, dob\u003dFri Mar 13 07:47:00 CET 1992, loves\u003d[carrot, papaya], weight\u003d600.0, gender\u003dm, vampires\u003d63.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df1e, name\u003dAurora, dob\u003dThu Jan 24 13:00:00 CET 1991, loves\u003d[carrot, grape], weight\u003d450.0, gender\u003df, vampires\u003d43.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df1f, name\u003dUnicrom, dob\u003dFri Feb 09 22:10:00 CET 1973, loves\u003d[energon, redbull], weight\u003d984.0, gender\u003dm, vampires\u003d182.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df21, name\u003dSolnara, dob\u003dThu Jul 04 02:01:00 CEST 1985, loves\u003d[apple, carrot, chocolate], weight\u003d550.0, gender\u003df, vampires\u003d80.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df22, name\u003dAyna, dob\u003dSat Mar 07 08:30:00 CET 1998, loves\u003d[strawberry, lemon], weight\u003d733.0, gender\u003df, vampires\u003d40.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df23, name\u003dKenny, dob\u003dTue Jul 01 10:42:00 CEST 1997, loves\u003d[grape, lemon], weight\u003d690.0, gender\u003dm, vampires\u003d39.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df24, name\u003dRaleigh, dob\u003dTue May 03 00:57:00 CEST 2005, loves\u003d[apple, sugar], weight\u003d421.0, gender\u003dm, vampires\u003d2.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df25, name\u003dLeia, dob\u003dMon Oct 08 14:53:00 CEST 2001, loves\u003d[apple, watermelon], weight\u003d601.0, gender\u003df, vampires\u003d33.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df26, name\u003dPilot, dob\u003dSat Mar 01 05:03:00 CET 1997, loves\u003d[apple, watermelon], weight\u003d650.0, gender\u003dm, vampires\u003d54.0}}Document{{_id\u003d554c72c81094a1039086df27, name\u003dNimue, dob\u003dMon Dec 20 16:15:00 CET 1999, loves\u003d[grape, carrot], weight\u003d540.0, gender\u003df}}"
```

I want to have a better visual of the DB information. What I can do? What are the code problems (a lot I think)?
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicitly relying on the toString() method of Document, which does not return a JSON string, try using the [toJson](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/org/bson/Document.html#toJson--) method.  There shouldn't be any need for GSON, as to toJson method already returns a JSON string.

You may, however, need to add additional JSON markup, since as is you will just get a series of JSON objects concatenated together.  But with a little extra work, you you turn that into a proper JSON array.